# How to access database using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm going through the reference docs - 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/jdbc.html to connect database from Web application using Spring architecture.

Here, the code creates a jdbcTemplate using the the datasource.

```
public class JdbcCorporateEventDao implements CorporateEventDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    // JDBC-backed implementations of the methods on the CorporateEventDao follow...
}
```

The datasource is defined in an xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="corporateEventDao" class="com.example.JdbcCorporateEventDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- the DataSource (parameterized for configuration via a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer) -->
    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I'm having hard time to understand -

1. Where to store this xml file? Is there any nomenclature for filenaming?
2. How is the datasource mapped in the code from xml? for eg. if i want to have another environment in the xml file, What should be the code that need to be touched?

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: You are looking at docs for spring v2, the latest release is 4, btw.

Comment: Check out these updated guides http://spring.io/guides

Comment: got it! Thank you @geoand... So what to use in production instead of SimpleDriverDataSource ?

Comment: I would use org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource. It's a very good Connection Pool that is also preferred by Spring Boot

Answer (score 2):

- You can store it anywhere and name it whatever you want! You create the beans by importing that xml file into your spring context.

For example, if I named my file datasource.xml and stored it under my **src/main/resources/config** folder:

```
<import resource="classpath:config/datasource.xml"/>
```

- I *think* you are asking how the datasource can be configured easily for different environments. There are many approaches to this--I typically create a few datasource files in a directory (usually the one I mentioned above)

  ```
  datasource.DEV.xml
  datasource.QA.xml
  datasource.PROD.xml
  ```

Each of these are configured to a different database. I then import by passing in a environment variable I call "env":

```
<import resource="classpath:config/datasource.${env}.xml"/>
```

If you are launching with Eclipse, you can specify that in the run configurations under the "Environment" tab.

Answer (score 1):

First use higher version of spring(3 and above) to use annotation effectively.

add below lines in your xml file

```
 <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

make your dao class as annotated with `@Repository`.

and inside this class use

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate
```

so your class should look like

```
@Repository
public class JdbcCorporateEventDao implements CorporateEventDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    // JDBC-backed implementations of the methods on the CorporateEventDao follow...
}
```

in future if you want to change your datasource then below code should be touched just to change the datasource reference

```
 <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>
```

here change `ref="new datasource"` for the datasource property

Comment: Thanks! My question here though is - 1) Where to place the xml file in the project structure? Is there a name which I should be giving? and 2) Can i have multiple datasources, for eg. a dev datasource, a staging datasource and a production datasource?

Comment: 1)you can place xml inside WEB-INF/Config folder or directly under WEB-INF folder 2)why do you want dev prod different datasource altogether..define single datasource like above xml and read properties like url uname passwd from dev.prop prod.prop file respectively because datasource for all environment has same properties..

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your first question.

Naming is just standard way of following. It is not specific.,

In general mostly use

```
application-context.xml, 
application-resource.xml
```

Answering to your second question

Talking about location of the files is not confined to any folder. As long you define the import resource properties in web.xml.

```
<import resource="yourpath/myxml.xml"/>
```

One more thing to say is : @Autowired is missing in your code. That migth be the reason for not getting the jdbcTemplate.

```
@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```